# Can't parse this JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-1.9

I'm getting some JSON data, the simplest example of which holding a single row is:

```
{ max: [[Date.UTC(2013,1,22,13,11,13), 999.0000]] }
```

It seems to be well formed:

```
>>> console.log({ max: [[Date.UTC(2013,1,22,13,11,13), 999.0000]] })
Object { max=[1]}
```

Though, if I try:

```
>>> $.parseJSON("{ max: [[Date.UTC(2013,1,22,13,11,13), 999.0000]] }");

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

Why is this?

Thanks guys, I hadn't realized the differences between JavaScript Object Notation and Strict JSON.  I changed it to output like this:

```
{ "max": [[1353007547000,70.0000]] }
```

The context of this data was for loading some HighCharts data via ajax, but all the examples were in the above format sans ajax.

Comment: Well... your JSON is invalid. *"It seems to be well formed"*: In this case you are interpreting it as JavaScript, and it is a valid object literal, but that is something different than JSON.

Comment: It is invalid - check it first http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still dealing in a ***JavaScript object <s>that is JSON-like</s>*** rather than true JSON. For .parseJSON you want strict JSON.

This means that your Date object needs to be a string and your property names need to be in double quotes.

Tools like http://jsonlint.com/ can often be super helpful.

@c4p suggests using JSON.stringify on your JavaScript object first, and that is often a good first step as it will often handle a lot of things that need adjusted prior to parsing.

Comment: *"JavaScript object that is JSON-like"* sounds really strange to me... object literal notation and JSON have nothing in common apart from that one was inspired by the other. I think your statement makes the difference between literal syntax and JSON only more confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling I agree that the phrase is really strange. However, I have often found that when describing this difference to folks who are newer to thinking about the difference between JSON and JavaScript objects, it is important to give a nod to their vague similarities first. While it may sound odd to you or I that is because we already understand the underlying difference between literal syntax and notation. Perhaps it would be better to say that JavaScript objects can often look similar to JSON(JavaScript Object Notation) but the similarities end once you get past their physical appearance.

Answer (score 7):

JSON is a strict standard, which happens to be a subset of Javascript. `Date` is one of this things it omits - if you want date, you'll have to transfer it as string (or int). You code is valid JavaScript, but not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you dump your Javascript object to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify({ max: [[Date.UTC(2013,1,22,13,11,13), 999.0000]] });

"{"max":[[1361538673000,999]]}"
```

Notice the `max` key became a string `"max"` and the `Date` was converted to a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Date is a javascript object and is not a part of JSON.  You are attempting to pass a javascript function call through the serialized form and this will not work.

The reason it works in the console log is due to the Date.UTC function resolving into a value before the console.log is called.  It looks like most likely this string was originally setup with the intent of being passed to eval(which executes literal javascript) which could execute the function and you are attempting to make it less vulnerable by using parseJSON(Which is good!).

The solution here depends on how much control you have over the JSON data you are receiving. If you have zero control then you may be forced to use eval. Otherwise the json should contain an array of the params(or the timestamp itself) passed to UTC and when its been parsed you need to call Date.UTC on the result to get your UTC date.